# Thread.joinable return true even thread hasn't finished executing

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, sfml

```
std::mutex MTX;
bool ExitThread = false;

//This function is running in a separate thread 
//for constantly trying to connect to a server in a non blocking manner
void ClientConnectingLoop(sf::TcpSocket* client, std::string ipAddress, 
unsigned short port)
{
    std::cout << "Start" << std::endl;
    MTX.lock();
    std::cout << "Start2" << std::endl;
    while(client->connect(ipAddress, port) != sf::Socket::Status::Done && 
    !ExitThread)
    {

    }

    std::cout << "Done" << std::endl;
    MTX.unlock();
}


int main()
{
    //Code for setting ipaddress and port is abstracted.
    std::string ipAddress;
    unsigned short port;

    //Setup socket
    sf::TcpSocket clientSocket;
    clientSocket.setBlocking(false);

    //Connect to server
    std::thread ClientConnectThread(ClientConnectingLoop, &clientSocket, ipAddress, port);
    std::cout << "Connecting to server......" << std::endl;


    //Wait until it finishes executing, code inside this loop is abstracted
    while(!ClientConnectThread.joinable())
    { 
    }

    //The thread is finished executing.
    if(ClientConnectThread.joinable())
    {
        std::cout << "Joinable returned true" << std::endl;
        ClientConnectThread.join();
    }

    //........
}
```

The problem comes to that the thread returns joinable (true) despite the loop in the thread is still running.

So that means the console outputs "Connecting to server......" => "Start" => "Start2" => "Joinable returned true" but "Done" should be printed after "Start2" unless I misunderstood joinable function

I am still fairly new to c++ and SFML, please be kind when pointing out any mistakes.

Comment: I think you misunderstood [`joinable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/joinable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting directly from [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/joinable)

> std::thread::joinable
>
> Checks if the thread object identifies an active thread of execution. Specifically, returns true if get_id() != std::thread::id(). So a default constructed thread is not joinable.
> A thread that has finished executing code, but has not yet been joined is still considered an active thread of execution and is therefore joinable.

Based on this, the idea of a joinable thread is different. A thread is always joinable except if has been default-constructed and has not been assigned to a function/method to run or if you have already called the `thread.join()` method on it.

An rather simple solution to the problem at hand would be to use some multithreading-aware locking construct such as [std::atomic](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) or [void futures](http://apprize.info/c/modern_1/7.html) to communicate the result as suggested in the [Effective Modern C++ book of Scott Meyers](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920033707.do)

Comment: Thanks for answering. I am just being dumb...  **Joinable** always returns true even the thread is not finished unless already joined.  But  **Join** blocks until the thread is finished executing.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, `std::thread` object is also _not joinable_ after calling `detach` member function and after moving from that object.